# With the boto library, can I avoid granting list permissions on a base bucket in S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I currently have an IAM role that has a policy like so:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::blah.example.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:ListBucket", "s3:PutObject", "s3:PutObjectAcl", "s3:DeleteObject"],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::blah.example.com/prefix/"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Boto seems to require the ListBucket permission be present on the root of the bucket to do the  get_bucket call. If I remove the first hash in the Statement array, get_bucket('blah.example.com') will fail. Here's the error text:

```
*** S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>xxxx</RequestId><HostId>yyyy</HostId></Error>
```

Is there any way to restrict listing of the bucket to a certain prefix (e.g. "prefix/") while still using boto?

**UPDATE**

In order to get everything working, I used the following policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::blah.example.com"
    ],
    "Condition":{
      "StringLike":{
         "s3:prefix":"prefix/*"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:PutObject", "s3:PutObjectAcl", "s3:DeleteObject"],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::blah.example.com/prefix/*"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

You still have to use the `validate=False` parameter to the `get_bucket` method, but it allows listing within the prefix.

Answer (score 5):

By default boto tries to validate the existence of a bucket by doing a LIST operation on the bucket, asking for zero results.  If you would prefer that it skip this validation step, just call it like this:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket', validate=False)
```

This should skip the LIST operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the list(prefix='prefix/') still seems to fail.

Comment: I see.  This is actually an S3 permissions issue, not a boto issue.  Well, maybe it's not fair to call it an issue.  It's just the way it works.  I don't think there is a way around it but I will investigate a bit more and report back if I find anything.

Comment: I found it. The second permission's resource needed to be "arn:aws:s3:::blah.example.com/prefix/*". The difference is the * at the end. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There was more to getting the list working. I apparently can't paste the policy in a comment.

Comment: Is it worth adding a new answer?