# AWS S3 ACL Issue between console login and api inconsistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm hoping someone may be able to shed some light on why I am having authorization errors between console login and api login.  I have a client with access to a specific S3 bucket that has full CRUD access to the bucket and is able to perform downloads, create, delete via console, but when access via API they can also download view if they know the key ahead of time but are receiving an unauthorized error when attempting to read the keys for the objects in the bucket.

The following policy is associated to a user account in attempt to isolate that user to only a single S3 Bucket.

```
 {
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListAndAlsoAllowGetBucketLocationRequiredForListBucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootLevelListingOfCompanyBucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:prefix": "",
          "s3:delimiter": "/"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The following is the api calls that is failing with an unauthorized:

```
-=-=-=-
import boto, boto.s3

s3conn = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                                         aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                                         is_secure=True,
                                         debug=0)

# This line fails with "403 Forbidden" b/c it tries to read the keys in # the bucket:
#s3bucket = s3conn.get_bucket('mybucket')

# This line does NOT try to read the keys and therefore succeeds:
s3bucket = s3conn.get_bucket('mybucket', validate=False)

# This loop fails with "403 Forbidden" on the very first iteration:
#for k in s3bucket.list():
#    print k

# This line works, but I had to use the webpage to learn the name of the # key first.
k = s3bucket.get_key('specificfilename.csv')
print k

# This line works.
print k.generate_url(expires_in=10) + '\n'
```

Comment: You should provide more details like the IAM policies associated with the user and any bucket policies you have set up.

Comment: What is the purpose of the condition on the s3:ListBucket?  It seems superfluous. It would be helpful to include examples of the calls to the APIs that are returning authorizations errors.

Comment: From the examples I used as reference it seemed to be a constraint of permissions to be able to view the designated folder, but I may have miss used and miss understood the sample.

Comment: Although I did notice when I remove that ListBucket with teh prefix and delimiter I was unable to see the target bucket getting an unauthorized error.

Comment: You might want to simply remove the condition, and not the whole statement.

Comment: Does this question shed any light on the situation?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478752/with-the-boto-library-can-i-avoid-granting-list-permissions-on-a-base-bucket-in  See the "UPDATE" section in the question.  It looks like the Questioner decided that the ListBucket policy needed a slightly different "Condition" statement; he needed to include a glob within the "s3:prefix" config itself.  Can you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bob Kinney mentioned, the problem is caused by this condition:

```
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "s3:prefix": "",
      "s3:delimiter": "/"
    }
  }
```

You're basically restricting the `ListBucket` action to calls that match that condition, but when you try to execute:

```
s3bucket = s3conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

boto will try to do a [list bucket call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) with no prefix and no delimiter to validate that the bucket exists and the user can access it. Since that call does not match your condition, it will fail.

The following does work:

```
s3bucket = s3conn.get_bucket('mybucket', validate=False)
```

because in this case boto simply skips the validation that I described above. And if you skip this validation and execute:

```
for k in s3bucket.list():
```

you end up with the same problem, since the `list()` call you're trying to run does not match your condition (prefix and delimiter are empty by default).

**To fix your IAM policy, simply remove that condition for the `ListBucket` action.**